# Using a field in update drastically slows down the query

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I am trying to go down a hierarchichal structure on oracle and I am having serious performance issues.
This is my code:

```
UPDATE {table} t1
SET (t1.{column2}) = (
    SELECT max(t2.{date}) FROM {table2} t2
    WHERE t2.{column} in(
        SELECT t3.{column}
        FROM {table3} t3
        START WITH t3.{columnt3} = 'blablabla'
        CONNECT BY t3.{columnt3} = PRIOR t3.{column}
        ))
WHERE t1.{column1} = 'blablabla'
```

This code works and runs in under one second.
Now, replacing the first **'blablabla'** with **t1.{column1}** (those two are equivalent) results in over one minute of execution time.
The code looks then like this:

```
UPDATE {table} t1
SET (t1.{column2}) = (
    SELECT max(t2.{date}) FROM {table2} t2
    WHERE t2.{column} in(
        SELECT t3.{column}
        FROM {table3} t3
        START WITH t3.{columnt3} = t1.{column1}
        CONNECT BY t3.{columnt3} = PRIOR t3.{column}
        ))
WHERE t1.{column1} = 'blablabla'
```

Does anybody know the reason for this strange problem?

**Edit:**
Here is the explain plan for the upper (the working) query:
[first explain plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfTSd.png)

And here the one for the second (the broken) query:
[second explain plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U23P6.png)

As you can see, the runtime is just exploding by searching through t2, a very big table.
But why does this happen? and is there a reason why this happens?

**Edit 2:**

Maybe the orginal code helps a bit more:

```
UPDATE tmp_obsolete t1
SET (liefertermin) = (
    SELECT max(versand_termin) FROM ropd7.pkvp
    WHERE artikel_nr in(
        SELECT pstp.artikel_nr
        FROM ropd7.pstp
        START WITH pstp.komponenten_art_nr =  'XX.XX.XX.XX.XX'
        CONNECT BY pstp.komponenten_art_nr = PRIOR pstp.artikel_nr
        ))
WHERE t1.artikel_nr = 'XX.XX.XX.XX.XX';


UPDATE tmp_obsolete t1
SET (liefertermin) = (
    SELECT max(versand_termin) FROM ropd7.pkvp
    WHERE artikel_nr in(
        SELECT pstp.artikel_nr
        FROM ropd7.pstp
        START WITH pstp.komponenten_art_nr =  t1.artikel_nr
        CONNECT BY pstp.komponenten_art_nr = PRIOR pstp.artikel_nr
        ))
WHERE t1.artikel_nr = 'XX.XX.XX.XX.XX';
```

Comment: Did you compare the execution plans?

Comment: `CONNECT BY t3.{columnt3} = t3.{column}` is this line correct? Usually you expect to see the PRIOR keyword in there somewhere. I.e. `CONNECT BY PRIOR t3.{columnt3} = t3.{column}` or `CONNECT BY t3.{columnt3} = PRIOR t3.{column}`, depending on which way your hierarchy is defined

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: yes I compared them and the later one just exploded. But this doesn't help very much, because I still can't explain, why this happens.

Comment: Looks like you're getting enough values returned by the updated hierarchical query on table3 that's causing a full table scan against table2 (guessing, since you didn't reference the table names in the execution plans)

Comment: Queries are not equivalent but results are. CBO see 'START WITH t3.{columnt3} = t1.{column1}' and cann't use index because he might check all rows and better use full scan despite in using predicate t3.{columnt3} = 'blablabla' where CBO can use index immediately

Comment: I am confused. As far as I know Oracle does not implement table alias referencing more than one subquery deep. Do you mean, in the first occurrence of "blahblahblah", when you replace it, you use the actual table name, not `t1`?

Comment: @mathguy yes I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no good solution to make this query run efficient, so I tried using a simple PL/SQL-function which returns the max(date) when giving the parameter.
And this works pretty good.
Going through ~1000 entries in under 400ms.

Thanks everybody for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Does rewriting the query help:

```
UPDATE {table} t1
SET (t1.{column2}) = (
    SELECT max(t2.{date})
      FROM {table2} t2
      JOIN {table3} t3
        ON t2.{column} = t3.{column}
     START WITH t3.{columnt3} = t1.{column1}
   CONNECT BY t3.{columnt3} = PRIOR t3.{column})
WHERE t1.{column1} = 'blablabl';
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I still got a full table access on t2, so it still takes ages to run.